# How do I give route name to a closure route in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Hi I have the following Lumen Route

```
$router->get('/end', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) use ($router) {
    $controller = $router->app->make('App\Http\Controllers\Legacy\EndLegacyController');
    return $controller->index($request);
});
```

I am trying to give it a **route name** so that I can use redirect to redirect to this route like `redirect()->route('name_of_route')`

so far I have tried

```
})->namedRoute['end'] = '/end'; // No Effect
})->name('end') //Undefined function
```

but it didn't work
here's a list of present routes
[image]

**Edit**
Because of my certain requirement, I can't use `['as' => 'end', 'uses'=> 'ControllerName@Action']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the following syntax: `$router->get('/end', ['as'=>'name_here', function()]);`

Comment: Thanks @ali, it worked, I have now a named route with closure