# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::name() in lumen-framework 8.0

Tags: laravel, lumen

Below is the error which is thrown when the api is being hit.

`Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::name()`

**web.php**

```
<?php

/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('login', 'UserController@login')->name("cms_login");
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/cms'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('login', 'UserController@login')->name("client_login");
});
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0"
    },
```

Comment: why you need to route name in `lumen` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give route name to a closure route in Lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158729/how-do-i-give-route-name-to-a-closure-route-in-lumen)

Comment: @KamleshPaul need  `login` function to be differentiated from 2 different website and mobile app login ...  so gave the names so that it can be fetched in function

Comment: @Sharath you can make comment there ? `lumen` doesn't come with `view` so no use of this feature. that's why they removed this

Comment: @KamleshPaul is there any way i can identify from which route the call came ?

Comment: `$route = $request->route();` and `$path = $request->getPathInfo();`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818477/how-to-get-the-current-route-on-middleware-in-lumen-framework